# How do I make my custom treeview accept the Enter key?

Tags: delphi, custom-controls, vcl

I've got a custom control that descends from TTreeView.  I'm trying to give it special behavior when the user presses ENTER while the control is focused, by giving it a WM_CHAR handler that responds to VK_RETURN, but it never gets called.

I tried making sure that it would accept all keyboard input by adding a WM_GETDLGCODE handler that says `msg.Result := msg.Result or DLGC_WANTALLKEYS;`.  Now it receives the ENTER key, but the arrow keys no longer work!

Anyone have any idea how I can fix this correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I always do

```
WM_GETDLGCODE: Message.Result := Message.Result or DLGC_WANTCHARS or
                                 DLGC_WANTARROWS or DLGC_WANTTAB or
                                 DLGC_WANTALLKEYS;
```

when writing text editors. Maybe you just forgot `DLGC_WANTARROWS`?

Comment: Thanks! That worked. You'd think something called WantAllKeys would mean that you want *all* keys, but I guess not.  Go figure.