# Missing keyboard input on custom VCL control

Tags: windows, delphi, keyboard, vcl

I have custom control which is `TScrollingWinControl` descendant but it doesn't receive `WM_KEYDOWN`. I used spy++ and it showed me that no such message is sent to the control. What should I do in order to be able to receive keyboard input.

Update: All that's needed was to call SetFocus in the WM_MOUSEDOWN handler. From this moment on the control starts receiving WM_KEYDOWN. Thanks to TLana and sorry for asking something that's already been asked [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2818811/why-wont-my-control-accept-keyboard-input).

Comment: Have you tried this http://stackoverflow.com/q/2818811/960757 ?

Comment: That's it. Thank you TLama! SetFocus on MouseDown resolved the problem.